# randomly select some numbers c#

Tags: c#

Let's say we have this numbers 51,53,58,60,78. How can we select a number randomly in such a way if its already selected/picked, it will not be selected in the next run.

Also, after all numbers are selected, everything is restarted and the process repeats itself.

Comment: It's not random if they can be anything, but not consecutive.

Comment: @Blake: I once heard about a mathematics professor who said that one can easily discern randomly-generated number sequences from human-generated-made-to-seem-random by the fact that the former would indeed have repeats.  In 1,000 random coin flips, for example, a truly random one can easily have well over a dozen consecutive identical results.  But if a human was creating it, it very likely would not.

Comment: @David: Another interesting fact about human vs reality-generated random numbers is that in some data sets, *numbers are far more likely to begin with the digit 1 than the digit 9*. This fact is usually called Benford's Law. It happens when things are scaled geometrically. Stock market indices, for example, spend a lot more time starting with 1 than with 2 because if they are doubling every 5 years then it takes 5 years to go from 1000 to 2000, but only 5 years to go from 2000 to 4000. You can use this to detect fraud; humans think that numbers are more likely to start with 5.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: And it has recently been used to establish that Greece's books are more likely to be cooked than other EU member states: [Fact and Fiction in EU-Governmental Economic Data](http://bit.ly/rdnnsx).

Comment: edited the question to make it consice, clear and simplified, kindly upvote. tnx

Comment: @user963499 I have further completed [the _correct_ answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7624362/85371) with a link to the answer of the existing duplicate question. Welcome to stackoverflow

Comment: What's wrong with Eric's answer? Knuth shuffle is the classic answer to this question. What do you expect out of more attention to the questino?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your integers into an array.  Create an instance of the `Random` class.  Call the `Random.Next(int minValue, int maxValue)` method with `0` being the minValue, and your array count minus 1 being your maxValue.  Then use that random integer to reference your integer array.

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int nextArrayIndex;
int[] randomNumbers = new int[] {51, 53, 58, 60, 78};

nextArrayIndex = rnd.Next(0, randomNumbers.Count() - 1);

Console.Writeline("Random Value: {0}", randomNumbers[nextArrayIndex].ToString());
```

*Edit: for non repeating data, just store the index that was already use of the integer array in a separate list and prior to utilizing the random number, do a check on the list to see if it was already used.  If so, then re-run the random number code.  If it is full, then don't allow that to continue in an endless loop.*

Comment: Note: this technique by itself will not satisfy the "no repeats" requirement.

Comment: This will very likely not satisfy the requirements that each number be chosen exactly once. In fact, it is essentially the birthday paradox that once we have chosen sufficiently many numbers, the probability that we repeat one we have already chosen is surprisingly high (in a list of 365 numbers, you have a larger than 50% of repeating after 23 choices).

Comment: @Jason you are absolutely right, I have edited in some quick and easy logic to prevent recurring random numbers.

Comment: @Surfer, your edit would still lead to a lot of collision checking. For a small sequence, you could keep plugging your way through it relatively quickly, but for larger sequences, you'll spend more and more time checking for repeats as the probabibility for collisions approaches 1. The "shuffle once" technique avoids that particular problem.

Comment: @surefer, jason, anthony,, ive added a new requirement. see the edited post tnx

Comment: @user963499, once you have reached the end, simply reshuffle (if you follow Eric's answer). You can shuffle as often as you need. Note: if you are reshuffling in rapid succession, you will want to hold onto your random number generator instance rather than re-instantiating.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram I agree with you, the "shuffle once" is the better approach.

Comment: As Anthony warns, storing a list of already used numbers is and performing collision checking will be very slow on large lists of numbers.  With a pseudo-random number generator, it may even hit an infinite loop.  Just use Knuth Shuffle.  Note that Knuth Shuffle can be performed one number one at a time rather than all at once, if pre-shuffling the entire list of numbers is not ideal.

Comment: Also, your collision checking does not scale. Imagine instead of 5 numbers it was a thousand. By the time you get to picking the 1000th number you'll have *hundreds* of collisions per number. The algorithm will get slower and slower as it runs. **This is a terrible way to prevent repeats.**

Comment: More effective is simply to remove the affected index.

Comment: Please provide more detailed information regarding how to avoid repeat numbers, since that seems to be a rather important detail here.

Answer (score 16):

Put the numbers into an array and then do the Knuth Shuffle on the array. The contents of the array are then in a random order, and if you iterate through it, you won't get repeats.

Be careful; it is easy to get the shuffle wrong.